# Php str_replace - two values to replace?

Tags: php, replace, str-replace

Using str_replace I want to change $url from this:

```
$url = http://example.com/images/lala1.jpg
```

to this

```
$url = http://example.com/images/lala1-0001.jpg
```

My problem is that I don't know how to insert the "-".

$url is changing so I really only know that it has ".jpg" at its' end.

My code so far:

```
for($i=1;$i<=9;$i++) {
    $array[] = str_replace('.jpg',sprintf("%04d",$i).'.jpg',$url); }
```

Any idea how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sprintf allows for regular characters in the arguments:

```
str_replace('.jpg', sprintf("-%04d.jpg", $i), $url);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make use of a [regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.introduction.php):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\.jpg$/', sprintf("-%04d.jpg",$i), $url);
```

This insures that it ONLY gets replaced at the end of the string.