# Make link form hashtags that stored in string

Tags: php, regex

For example I have this variable:

```
$test = "#stack #overflow #facebook";
```

Now I want to make simple link with this hashtags such as:

```
<a href="http:/facebook.com/stack">stack</a>
<a href="http:/facebook.com/overflow">overflow</a>
<a href="http:/facebook.com/facebook">facebook</a>
```

I don't know which hastags stored this variable and how can I do this action simply by `str_replace?

I read this link but I can do that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5862395/1830228

Comment: Regex is the answer ;-)

Comment: @haby yes, but how can i use that?

Comment: @anubhava Thanks, can be support UTF-8?

Comment: `$test = preg_replace('/#([\pL\pN-]+)/u', '<a href="http:/facebook.com/$1">$1</a>', $test);` to support `UTF-8`

Comment: @anubhava this code work fine, but couldn't detect UNDERLINE between hashtag words for example: `#stack_over_flow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer.

You can use a `preg_replace` like this to support `UTF-8`:

```
$test = preg_replace('/#([\pL\pN_-]+)/u',
          '<a href="http:/facebook.com/$1">$1</a>', $test);
```

Regex `#[\pL\pN_-]+` matches a `#` followed by 1+ unicode alphanumeric or `_` or `-` characters.